# Itead Arduino BT jumpers

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I'm trying to enter on the command mode on this board http://iteadstudio.com/store/images/produce/Platform/ArduinoCom/IteaduinoBT/iteaduinoBT_DS.pdf.

It is a bad-documented, no support Arduino BT clone. I would like to send some AT commands, but Its not working.

Just to make sure that i'm not doing something wrong, i would like to double check the jumpers configuration. As you can see in the Datasheet lnked above, we have two positions for the jumpers (in a 6 pins set, it confuses me already, because with 6 pins, we should have 3 combinations, and not 2 as described)

So from the picture attached[image: jumpers] which are the A,B and C(?!): red: A, yellow: B?

**EDIT**

From the data sheet:

a jumper to set the connections of HC-05. When the jumper is set in B, the HC-05 communicates to FT232R, when the jumper is set to A, the HC-05 communicates to Atmega328P(board).

I was just able to enter in the command mode, setting the SWITCH to CMD, Jumpers at A (as cited in the accepted answer) and connected via USB, 38400. It means: the data sheet is wrong, it inverted the operations between jumpers A and B, right? AFAIK the communication HC-05 - FT232R is the serial communication that I used between my computer and the HC05 via cable and not bt, right?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean. I think best is to elaborate/clarify 2nd part of your question a bit more in a new question here as it is out of scope of the original question; the question is set to 'Answered' so subject matter experts will probably not look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [circuit diagram](http://iteadstudio.com/store/images/produce/Platform/ArduinoCom/IteaduinoBT/sch-Iteaduinio%20BT.pdf). I think (with respect to your image above) it is supposed to be two parallel jumpers, oriented horizontally. They either go both on the left, or both on right.

```
 B A            B                A
o o o          o-o o          o o-o
o o o          o-o o          o o-o
```

Comment: I just updated my question, looks like the DS is wrong. what do you think, based in my updates